Accelerated Gambler's Ruin
In the classic gambler's ruin, we have Alice starting with $a$ chips and Bob (or the Bank) with $b$ chips, and each time Alice either gains $1$ chip from Bob with probability $p$ or loses $1$ chip to Bob with probability $q=1-p$.  They stop when either Alice or Bob have $0$ chips left and so are ruined.

If the game is fair with $p=q=\frac12$, then the probability Alice is ruined is $\frac{b}{a+b}$ and that Bob is ruined is $\frac{a}{a+b}$.  The expected number of bets before someone is ruined is $ab.$

If the game is unfair with $p\not=q\not=\frac12$, then the probability Alice is ruined is $\frac{p^bq^a−q^{a+b}}{p^{a+b}−q^{a+b}}$ and that Bob is ruined is $\frac{p^{a+b}-p^bq^a}{p^{a+b}−q^{a+b}}$.  The expected number of bets before someone is ruined is $\frac{bp^{a+b}+aq^{a+b}-(a+b)p^bq^a}{(p-q)(p^{a+b}-q^{a+b})}.$



A recent question asked about what I would call an accelerated gambler's ruin. Rather than betting $1$ each time, the bet size is the smaller of Alice's bankroll and Bob's bankroll at that time; in poker terms, they are all-in every time. This would be expected to be much faster because  somebody may be ruined after each bet. For a fair game, the probability somebody is ruined after each bet is at least $\frac12$ so the expected number of bets is bounded above by $2$. If $a=b$, whether fair or unfair, someone will be ruined after the first bet, making the expected number of bets $1$.

If the game is fair with $p=q=\frac12$, then the probability Alice is ruined is still $\frac{b}{a+b}$ and that Bob is ruined is still $\frac{a}{a+b}$ given the fairness of the game.  We can show that the expected number of bets before someone is ruined is $2$, unless $\frac{a+b}{\text{hcf}(a,b)}$ is a power of $2$ using the highest common factor (or greatest common divisor if you prefer) in which case the expected number of bets is $2\left(1-\frac{\text{hcf}(a,b)}{a+b}\right).$

What can we say about the probabilities of ruin and expected number of bets in an unfair accelerated game? Intuitively, the higher stakes should help the disadvantaged player $\big($Alice if $p < \frac12\big)$ compared to the classic gambler's ruin.



Side note: this fair accelerated gambler's ruin is a practical way of simulating any desired probability between $0$ and $1$: simply choose $a$ and $b$ so that $a/(a+b)$ is that probability, give the two outcomes virtual bankrolls, and play until the outcome is decided. Indeed the probability $p$ doesn't even have to be rational: just choose $a=p$ and $b=1-p$ and play with real-valued bankrolls. I seem to remember that some famous STEM person used to use this method (with coin flips) to decide who pays the bill....
